# Oauth 2.0 library use in Android

Tags: android, oauth-2.0

Can anyone suggest an Oauth2.0 client-server authentication library example for Android?

Comment: What is an 'OAuth 2.0 client-server authentication library'? If you just want to get tokens from a server, you don't really need a library. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Should have google'd before SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A while ago I worked on a project where we forked an Android application and added OAuth2 support: https://github.com/xebia/Mustard-macnos-fork
I don't think we used a library for it, we only used a library on the server side.

Since it's a while ago I don't remember the exact details, so maybe the commit log can help you further.

Comment: Another useful approach of Oauth library development which i found is by referring www.dwolla.com which provides a very good example to develop a our own Oauth2 library.